# Simple java - do while loop

Tags: java, do-while

Hi i have a question on do while loop. I am a novice starting out so im guessing this is quite a simple question.

I have this program:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int value = 0;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter a number");
            value = input.nextInt();
        }

        while (value != 5);
        {

            System.out.println("Got 5!");
        }
    }
}
```

Which is turn produces Got 5! when the input is 5, and it works. What my question is, why doesn't "got 5!" execute when the value input is not 5, as the condition states "value != 5" and the Sysout is within that condition. Doesn't the condition have to be true to execute?

I got this example from a tutorial and did not write it out myself that is why i am a bit confused.

Answer (score 10):

`while (value != 5);` is the condition of the `do-while` loop. As long as value != 5, that loop never terminates, and you never reach the `System.out.println("Got 5!");` line.

Perhaps it would become clearer if you re-arrange the code :

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int value = 0;
do {
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    value = input.nextInt();
}
while (value != 5);

System.out.println("Got 5!");
```

> the condition states "value != 5" and the Sysout is within that condition.

No, the `System.out.println` is not within the condition.

The `value != 5` condition is not connected in any way to the block that contains the `System.out.println("Got 5!");` statement, which is why I removed the curly braces of that block.

Comment: Oh ok! I did a few more tests and understand now. Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't care for empty lines, but humans do. Allow me to rewrite the code so it will be clearer:

```
do {
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    value = input.nextInt();
}
while (value != 5);

{
    System.out.println("Got 5!");
}
```

Or even (there is no reason to put the print statement in a block of its own):

```
do {
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    value = input.nextInt();
} while (value != 5);

System.out.println("Got 5!");
```

It is now easier to notince that the 'while' keword and its predicate are part of the do-while compound statement, and not related to the print statement. The code inside the do-while is executed again and again, until the condition is false. Only then the following code executes.

Comment: It's so obvious now, I was thinking into it too much i guess! cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Please read the syntax of [Do-while loop](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_do_while_loop.htm)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int value = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        value = input.nextInt();
    } while (value != 5); // This do-while loop exits if input is 5.

    // The below code is a normal block of code, which is executed
    // without any condition, only after execution of above loop
    // completes.
    {
        System.out.println("Got 5!");
    }
}
```